# error MSB4019: The imported project Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" was not found

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

When I build a solution in VS2013, I am getting this error.

```
error MSB4019: The imported project
"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v12.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" was not found.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file referenced is included in the Visualization and Modeling SDK.

You are going to need [Visual Studio 2012 Visualization & Modeling SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30680)

[VS2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30668)
[VS2013](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40754)

Comment: Is this no longer available for VS2013? The links are broken and I can't find it anywhere via google.

Answer (score 1):

Find this line in the .csproj text :

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets" />
```

and change the value of the project into

```
"$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TextTemplating\Microsoft.TextTemplating.targets"
```

Then reload the project in solution explorer of visual studio